# Replace a word based on a pattern in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, svg

I am converting SVG to PNG and I need to remove the angularjs attributes in my SVG.

```
<rect fill="#F9B24F" ry="5" rx="5" ng-attr-y="{{node.rectY}}" ng-attr-x="{{node.rectX}}" 
  ng-attr-height="{{chart.height}}" ng-attr-width="{{chart.width}}" y="10" x="20"    
height="80" width="160">
```

I need ouput as

```
<rect fill="#F9B24F" ry="5" rx="5"  y="10" x="20"    
height="80" width="160">
```

I am trying to replace using String Replace method in javascript.I have tried the following in console,but it's not working

```
"ng-repeat='{{dddddsd}}' dfjdzjfhjk".replace(/ng-*\s/g," ");
```

Comment: Don't you have to make the replacement in the source instead of at run time?

Comment: I am using AngularJS ng-repeat for making a flow chart by repeating a set of SVG elements. If I remove them at source, I wont be able generate SVG dynamically based on AJAX response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If** you can rely on the Angular attributes *always* being in the form `ng-xyz="..."`, you can do it like this:

```
str = str.replace(/\bng-[^\s]+="[^"]*"/g, '');
```

If some are in single quotes, you can follow up with a second `replace`:

```
str = str.replace(/\bng-[^\s]+='[^']*'/g, '');
```

Obviously that's a big "if," but it's the kind of "if" that you have to have if you want to manipulate SGML-like markup with regular expressions, which [fundamentally you can't really do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Example:

```js
var str = '<rect fill="#F9B24F" ry="5" rx="5" ng-attr-y="{{node.rectY}}" ng-attr-x="{{node.rectX}}" ng-attr-height="{{chart.height}}" ng-attr-width="{{chart.width}}" y="10" x="20"    height="80" width="160">';
display("Before: " + str);
str = str.replace(/\bng-[^\s]+="[^"]*"/g, '');
display("After: " + str);

function display(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = String(msg).replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;");
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Very much. I was trying all combinations of \w,[a-z] etc.

Answer (score 1):

don't use regex to parse DOM. (detailed answers on why here: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1733489#1733489))

Just walk the DOM and strip any attributes you don't want.

```
var svg = $('#mySvg').clone(); //see http://api.jquery.com/clone/
var allNodes = svg.find('*');

allNodes.each( function(i,node) {
    //Here you can extract any attribute starting with ng- but not all angular directives
    //start with ng-*
    node.removeAttribute('ng-repeat');
} );
```

Comment: Thanks..If I remove the attributes, I wont be be able to generate next Flow Chart dynamically as data bindings will be lost. Inkscape does not have issue with ng-attr and ng-repeat,  but canvg library has. I will remember your solution, it will be definitely useful for me.

Comment: You can proceed the attribute removal on a cloned version of your svg element